# Why should I use ember install over NPM or yarn?

Tags: ember.js, npm, ember-cli, package-managers, yarnpkg

I'm new to ember and I discover the command `ember install pkg` and I'm wondering why such package instead of using external package manager such as `yarn` or `npm` which are industry-wide/de-facto standard.

#### Question

Why should I use ember install over NPM or yarn?

Answer (score 8):

`ember install addon-name` is a short hand for `npm install --save-dev addon-name && ember g addon-name`

Comment: If yarn is used it will be used instead. I think it depends if you have a `yarn.lock`.

Comment: The point likely being - that when npm is gone... and the yarn has all been eaten by the cats... and there is some new 'thing,' ember install will probably work with whatever that *thing* is.

Comment: So it only syntactic sugar?

Answer (score 6):

The [documentation](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/) provides the answer for this one (ctrl + f ember install):

> Installs the given addon into your project and saves it to the
>   package.json file. If provided, the command will run the addon’s
>   default blueprint.

[The release notes for version 0.1.5](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases/tag/v0.1.15) provide a clue for this as well:

> #2805 Added the install:addon command, which installs an addon with NPM and then runs the included generator of the same name if it
>   provides one.

So, ember install is just a replacement for npm in most cases but when a blueprint is provided it will run those as well.